# UWP app using Windows Notification Service and VPN

Tags: uwp, wns

We currently developed a UWP app and have push notifications working.  However, the problem arises when users are on VPN the WNS channel does not get created and the app is no longer able to receive push notifications or register with notification hub.  The channel is getting created here

```
var attempts = 0;
try{
    PushNotificationChannel channel = null;
    do
    {
        channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
        attempts++;
    }while(channel == null && attempts< 3);
}
```

This works on the corp network a channel is created and the device gets registered with notification hub.  On VPN the channel does not get created.  Anyone experience this before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a bug with our Cisco vpn client, even though split tunneling is disabled, the client was trying to send wns traffic directly to the internet instead of down the tunnel.  Once exceptions were made for wns endpoints the uwp app was able to obtain a channel.